# Ford Fiesta Titanium 90 TDCI 2008 Vents Only working on face blowers

Tags: ford, repair, climate-control

I have a Ford Fiesta Titanium 90 TDCI 2008 plate.

The other day I went to demist my windscreen and after about 4 minutes I was wondering why it was not demisting. I put my hand over the dash blowers and noticed there was no air coming from the vent only from the front face blowers.

I thought I would test the foot blowers and they also do not work. So the only thing that blows is the front face blowers. All other climate controls work such as the blower speed, temperature and air conditioning.

Can anyone share some light on what the issue may be? I have searched many forums and cannot find a solution.

I have circled the controls that are not working in a red circle and the green circle the one that is working.

[image: Ford Fiesta]

Comment: I don't really know how similar is A/C in Fiesta and Focus, but on the latter air is directed into specific areas by small, electronically controlled flaps. If they fail or if the A/C control unit fails, they would be stuck like this. The only thing that comes to my mind that doesn't include disassembling whole dashboard is to reset the car by disconnecting the battery for a few minutes and connecting it again. If it's caused by hanged electronic unit, disconnecting it's power source should do the job. Otherwise I'd check the unit itself.

Comment: @Mark Thanks Mark I will try this method and see if it work, I will keep you posted on an update.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know Fiesta but found similar case on [polish Ford forum](https://forum.fordclubpolska.org/showthread.php?t=209613). There is one particular info that might be very useful. I'll try to translate, maybe it would show you the right direction.

> Recently, the ability to change the airflow has stopped working for me. The central airflow was left and it could not be changed either on the legs or on the window. One colleague from the forum instructed me to check if by accident the cord did not come out of the selector (the one in the middle console near the gas pedal). I checked and it turned out that this plastic selector which enters the rod with the motor was broken. And it broke because the engine used to steer badly. I replaced the engine with another one but still the same.
>   Generally, if you press one button for example (let's say the button for the legs) the selector should move once to the right and when pressed the same button again - to the left returning to the same place where it was before the first press. In my case, if you press this button 30 times, the selector will do about 300 degrees rotation. That's why this selector broke - because there is a limiter that blocked it (in the photo this white plastic).

Unfortunatelly the photo isn't available anymore. But check this console near the gas pedal. Maybe the tie controlling the airflow actually disconnected from the steering motor.

Comment: Cheers Mark this is excellent, I will try this method also and give you an update :D much appreciated for your time.